# How to format python text for POS Printer

Tags: python

I have been able to write python code that prints a bunch of text using receipt style.

On a regular full size printer I get the print out as expected with correct formatting and it looks like so.

[image: Normal Printer]

However on a POS printer (Thermal Receipt Printer Model POS - 8330), the text is not formatted exactly as I expect it to, here is an example of the output
[image: POS Printer]

The code is exactly the same. How are POS printer texts formatted using python?

CODE

```
companyName = "Hilton Steel and Cement"
paytype = self.payment_Mode
companyName = companyName + "\n\nSale Receipt\n\nOpp Golden Line Mall\nP.O BOX 3404-20100\n TEL: 0727441192\nEMAIL: Hiltonltd@yandex.com"
receiptNo = randint(1, 100000)
finalString = companyName + "\n\nReceipt No:" + str(receiptNo) + "\n\n" + self.getproductList()\
                              + "\n______________________________________\n" + "Total Due:        " + str(self.totaltoBePaid)  + "\n______________________________________\n\n" + "Paid In:     " + paytype + "\n\n"+ "Served By:     " + str(self.user) +"\n" + "Payment:           " + str(self.finalvariables[1])+ "\nBalance:            " + str(self.finalvariables[0])  + "\n\n\nWelcome Back"


open(self.filename, "w").write(finalString)
os.startfile(self.filename, "print")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the printer only supports a limited line length, and auto-wraps long lines.

If [this](http://www.bilkur.com/products/Palmx_ZJ-8330.htm) is the printer in question, it has a print width of 72 mm, and three (I assume monospaced) fonts, with letter widths of 3 mm, 1.5 mm or 1.1 mm.
That means you can have *at most* 24, 48 or 65 characters per line, depending on the font you pick (and assuming no side margins).  The linked site has a programming manual available.

Comment: your answer pointed me to the right direction, however am still stuck with implementation as the programming manual is pretty advanced for me to apply its content, are you in position to help out with that? I asked a new question just for that. Eliminating the huge side margins and reducing font is the biggest huddle https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64858365/how-to-format-python-string-for-particular-pos-printer