# How to format Python String for particular POS printer

Tags: python

I am using a Thermal Receipt Printer POS-8330 found [HERE](http://www.bilkur.com/products/Palmx_ZJ-8330.htm)

I am writing code that sends a python string to the printer, here is the code that accomplishes this

```
companyName = "Hilton Steel and Cement"
paytype = self.payment_Mode
companyName = companyName + "\n\nSale Receipt\n\nOpp Golden Line Mall\nP.O BOX 3404-20100\n TEL: 0727441192\nEMAIL: Hiltonltd@yandex.com"
receiptNo = randint(1, 100000)
finalString = companyName + "\n\nReceipt No:" + str(receiptNo) + "\n\n" + self.getproductList()\
                              + "\n______________________________________\n" + "Total Due:        " + str(self.totaltoBePaid)  + "\n______________________________________\n\n" + "Paid In:     " + paytype + "\n\n"+ "Served By:     " + str(self.user) +"\n" + "Payment:           " + str(self.finalvariables[1])+ "\nBalance:            " + str(self.finalvariables[0])  + "\n\n\nWelcome Back"

open(self.filename, "w").write(finalString)
os.startfile(self.filename, "print")
```

The printer has a programming manual found [HERE](http://www.bilkur.com/download/Palmx/Dokuman/Palmx_ZJ-8330_Programmer_Manual.pdf), but I cannot make out anything off of it or particularly how to apply it. Kindly give me some help with the following

1. To reduce the font-size
2. To reduce the horizontal margins so that the print out can start from the furthest left.

The code I have written gives this result on the POS printer. [image]

On a regular full size printer it gives

[image: this]

which is exactly what I want.

Comment: May be this might help https://learn.adafruit.com/mini-thermal-receipt-printer/circuitpython

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the manual, this printer uses [control characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character) (the first 32 characters in ASCII) to start commands and separate them from text.

So you can intersperse text and printer commands. Just make sure to open the output file in `binary` mode!

For example, looking at page 17 of the programming manual, the command `ESC @` resets the printer.
This command consists of two characters (bytes); decimal 27 followed by decimal 64.
You can create that command as follows:

```
In [7]: bytes([27,64])
Out[7]: b'\x1b@'
```

You have to set the left margin (command `GS L`, page 37) and the printing area width (command `GS W`, page 38).
Note that "horizontal motion units" is explained in the `GS P` command on page 38. The default horizontal motion unit is 25.4/180 = 0.1411 mm or 1/180 = 0.0055 inches.

So if you want to set the left margin to approximately 5 mm (4.94 mm to be precise), you have to send the following command:

```
dIn [14]: bytes([29, 76, 35,0])
Out[14]: b'\x1dL#\x00'
```

The value 35 is calculated like this:

```
In [13]: round(5/(25.4/180))
Out[13]: 35
```

If you also want to set the printing width to 60 mm, then the argument for the `GS W` command would have to be:

```
In [15]: round(60/(25.4/180))
Out[15]: 425
```

This is larger than 255, so it would have to be spread over two bytes;

```
In [17]: 425-256
Out[17]: 169
```

The command would be:

```
In [18]: bytes([29, 87, 169,1])
Out[18]: b'\x1dW\xa9\x01'
```

You can combine these commands, I think:

```
In [20]: bytes([29, 76, 35, 0, 29, 87, 169,1])
Out[20]: b'\x1dL#\x00\x1dW\xa9\x01'
```

**Edit:**

Adding the print commands to the data is easy:

```
printdata = b'\x1dL#\x00\x1dW\xa9\x01' + finalString.encode('utf-8')
```

Note that you do need to `encode` the string, since the printer commands are binary.

Also note that you need to write the string to a file in *binary* mode.

```
with open(self.filename, "wb") outf:
    outf.write(printdata)
os.startfile(self.filename, "print")
```

Finally, I used `with` so that the file is properly closed after writing. The way you are using it leaves the file open.

Comment: @Ronald Smith, thanks a lot,  how can I add the last 2 commands with the print statement  
open(self.filename, "w").write(finalString)
os.startfile(self.filename, "print")

Comment: @JohnnKaita Just prepend them to the `finalString`.

Comment: @Ronald Smith over a week later I am still struggling with this issue, do you  think you might go to further detail and explain how I would prepend to the finalString variable with an example...I asked similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64887697/how-to-combine-and-send-in-out-commands-to-printer-with-string, currently the product is being used with a workaround, in which I convert the string to a pdf, then send it to browser and they can edit the print settings from there, however this is still toooooo slow and unrealistic for the busieness.

Comment: @Ronald Smith , thank you so much after several attempts it has worked, can't wait to see the smile on the operator's face